# How to log out from facebook in my site

Tags: php, facebook, session, kohana, logout

I'm using `https://github.com/pocesar/facebook-kohana` for facebook login. I have problem with facebook logout. It doesn't destroy facebook session. I've tried so many things and I've read many questions. I tried this in my logout method, but no result:
`$this->redirect('https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?
    next=mysite.dev
    &access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN');`

My logout method is:

```html
  public  function action_logout(){
         $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => 'appId',
            'secret' => 'mySecret',
        ));
         $user = $facebook->getUser();

        $facebook->destroySession();
        Session::instance()->delete('user');
     
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
```

How to destroy session, so that user can log in my site with another facebook account? Thanks!

My method login is:

```html
 public function action_fbLogin(){
      
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => 'appId',
            'secret' => 'Secret',
        ));

        $user = $facebook->getUser();
       
        if ($user) {

            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me', array('fields' => 'id,email,name,first_name,last_name,picture')); 
          
            $user_id = Model_UserFunctions::checkIfUserExist($user_profile['email']); 
            if($user_id > 0)
            {
                
                Session::instance()->set('user', array(
                    'fb_id' => $user_profile['id'],
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'pic' => $user_profile['picture'],
                    'email' => $user_profile['email'],
                    'first_name' =>  $user_profile['first_name'],
                    'last_name' =>  $user_profile['last_name'],
                ));
                
                //var_dump($_SESSION);
                $this->redirect('profile');
                exit;
            }
            $values = array(
                    'email' => $user_profile['email'],
                    'username' => $user_profile['email'],
                    'password' => '12345678'
                );
            $user = ORM::factory ( 'User' );
            $user->values($values);
            try
            {
                if($user->save()){
                    $user_new_id = $user->as_array();
                    $user_new_id = $user_new_id['id'];
                    Session::instance()->set('user', array(
                            'fb_id' => $user_profile['id'],
                            'user_id' => $user_new_id,
                            'pic' => $user_profile['picture'],
                            'email' => $user_profile['email'], 
                            'first_name' => $user_profile['first_name'],
                            'last_name' => $user_profile['last_name'],
                        ));
                    
                    $this->redirect('profile');
                }


            }
            catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
            {
                $result = $e->errors('models');
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($result);
                exit;
            }


        }
        else 
        {
            
            $this->redirect($facebook->getLoginUrl(array('id,email,name,first_name,last_name,picture'))); 
        }
        exit;
    
    }
```

Edited: My goal to use Facebook logout is because in my site I only use Facebook login, there isn't another way to log in my site, that's idea of it. And I should have logout method in my site, so when user wants to logout, he could do it.
This logouts me from facebook but facebook login page is shown. How to redirect next to my site. I've set it as next but it doesn't redirect to it:

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?
    next=http://mysite.dev
    &access_token=Null">Logout</a>`

Comment: but... they just need to log in with another account on facebook...
I don't think you can log them off of their facebook account IN facebook from within you site.

Comment: Isn't it way to log out from their facebook or just to kill facebook session that is in my site? :) I have button for facebook login, I set session and that's why I want to logout user from my site.

Comment: Forgive me but I don't understand... If you log me out of your site and I am still logged in in Facebook... then I come back to a page on your site I am still using the same FB account so you cannot log me in with a different one. While if I login in facebook with a different one or if I am not logged in on Facebook THEN... you could accept me with a different one or ask me to log in on FB first

Comment: Yes, that's right. Now, the only way to log out from my site is to log out from facebook. My question is, is there any way to kill facebook session or yo log out from facebook in my site using logout method?

Comment: @ci_lover — Can you edit your question to make it clear that your goal is to log the user (using Facebook as an authentication provider) out of your site and not to log them out of their facebook account?

Answer (score 0):

You can get facebook logout url using facebook-php-sdk API.
When user will click on that url he will be offline from his facebook account.

```
if ($user) {
   $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

For more info you can check this url.

https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: I used it -> `$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
        $this->redirect( $logoutUrl);` but it redirects to `https://www.facebook.com/home.php` , it doesn't logout.

Comment: $facebook->getLogoutUrl() is the only way to logout facebook account using php. So please check it properly or show us some more code.

Comment: I edited my question, I added my method for login and there is also method for logout there. $facebook->getLogoutUrl() doesn't logout me.

Comment: @ci_lover check your facebook app configuration and logout redirect url also.

Comment: What to check in it. What options should be set for logout? My redirect url is proper-it's my site.

Answer (score 0):

Then you don't have a problem with facebook

Is only the session that needs to be destroyed...

On this page of PHP manual there is an example showing you might need aditional steps to destroy a session beyond `unset($_SESSION)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Forcing the users to log off from Facebook does not seem a good move for me.

Millions of FB users have intentionally asked to stay logged in and if they visit your site and logoff from there they might think it wasn't very friendly of you to log them off the FB accounts. many don't even remember their pwd... so you would be creating a problem for them and they might never comeback to your site... Just saying

Comment: You can not logout user from facebook by just destroy PHP session.

Comment: @DharmeshGoswami — the OP wants to log the user out of their own site, not facebook

Comment: I posted this answer only after exchanging comments with @ci_lover to understand that the question was not about login in/off facebook but the site